# Как объединить два словаря с одинаковым значением

Tags: python

После некоторой обработки текстов получаю такой список словарей:

```
[{'word': 'житель', 'count': 2, 'id': [1, 3]}, {'word': 'житель', 'count': 1, 'id': [2]}, {'word': 'зачинщик', 'count': 1, 'id': [0]}]
```

Необходимо объединить объединять только те словари, в которых "word" одинаковые чтобы получить следующий вид:

```
[{'word': 'житель', 'count': 3, 'id': [1, 2, 3]}, {'word': 'зачинщик', 'count': 1, 'id': [0]}]
```

Пыталась использовать такой код:

```
for i in range(0, len(a)-1):
    if a[i]["word"] == a[i+1]["word"]:
        a[i]["count"] = a[i]["count"] + a[i+1]["count"]
        a[i]["id"] = a[i]["id"] + a[i+1]["id"]
        a[i+1].clear
print(a)
```

Но второй словарь не удаляется.

Есть ли более короткая форма выполнения данных операций?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

такой код устроит?

```
data = [{'word': 'житель', 'count': 2, 'id': [1, 3]}, {'word': 'житель', 'count': 1, 'id': [2]}, {'word': 'животное', 'count': 1, 'id': [111]}]    
res = dict()

for obj in data:
    if obj['word'] not in res:
        res[obj['word']] = obj
    else:
        res[obj['word']]['count'] += obj['count']
        res[obj['word']]['id'] += obj['id']

print(res)
```

он также позволяет анализировать когда `word` разные, или нужно и по другим ключам независимо соединять записи?

P.S.

поле `id` получается неотсортированное, если требуется сортировка, то можно далать

```
    if obj['word'] not in res:
        res[obj['word']] = obj
    else:
        res[obj['word']]['count'] += obj['count']
        res[obj['word']]['id'] += obj['id']
        res[obj['word']]['id'].sort()
```

Comment: нужно объединять только те словари, в которых "word" одинаковые, остальные трогать не надо.

Comment: @ЕленаСергеева как это можно было понять из вашего вопроса?

Comment: так я так и сделал - можете проверить код

Comment: а можно ли получить отдельно значения словаря "res"?

Comment: `res['житель']` вернет вам `{'word': 'житель', 'count': 3, 'id': [1, 2, 3]}`

Comment: @Zhihar, спасибо Вам

Answer (score 0):

```
l = [{'word': 'житель', 'count': 2, 'id': [1, 3]}, {'word': 'житель', 'count': 1, 'id': [2]}]
res ={x:(l[0][x]+l[1].get(x) if (type(l[0][x]) != str) else l[0][x]) for x in l[0].keys()}
```

res:

```
{'word': 'житель', 'count': 3, 'id': [1, 3, 2]}
```

Comment: Индексация выглядит некрасиво, я бы сразу распаковал в две переменные `l1, l2 = ...`

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]